# Python package not showing in https://pypi.org/simple/

Tags: python, package, pypi

I just published a package on PyPI (https://pypi.org/project/phmod/) but it does not show up in the list of packages available at https://pypi.org/simple/.

To build the package, I used:

```
$ python -m setup sdist bdist_wheel
```

And to publish it, I used:

```
$ python -m twine upload dist/*
```

I wonder if there are additional steps I need to take for the package to be included in https://pypi.org/simple/.

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, start here: https://pypi.org/simple/phmod/ — the package is there, ok, check. Second: `curl https://pypi.org/simple/ | grep -Fw phmod` — oops, really, it's not there (or `wget -O-` but that's doesn't matter much). Seems like there're delays in index updates.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I think there are delays in index updates.